# best way to parallelization in shell

Tags: macos, shell, parallel-processing

I have an experiment that I need to execute many times and track the execution time of it.

My python code needs to run multiple times with different inputs but also multiple times for the same input to get the average time of execution for every single input.

I am thinking of using parallelization ( and I am doing this in bash)but I don't know how to approach it because I need to keep track of everything and then represent results in a graph.

My concerns is that if I want to have everything in one file with the command `parallel` I will have unordered data since I can't control which job ends first. If I decide to for example have all the output of a certain input in one file (assigned to this specific input) and then get the average out of it, I will end up with many files and this might make the next step more difficult.

I am not asking for code, I just want a better idea(if possible) of an algorithm I can use. maybe a way of controling the order of jobs(FIFO) created by `parallel`, another tool of parallelization maybe...? Help

Comment: `parallel` reassembles output data into order. That's one of the reasons to use it in favor to my usual preference of (simpler, fewer-things-happening-behind-your-back) `xargs -P`.

Comment: That said, right now this question trends towards broad and opinion-based, because it doesn't specify a narrow, specific, objectively-testable definition for "best". See [Why is asking a question on best practice a bad thing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142353/why-is-asking-a-question-on-best-practice-a-bad-thing) on [meta], paying particular attention to [Kevin B's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/322777/144918).

Comment: That said, if you're parallelizing invocations of Python code, why not use the [Python `multiprocessing` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) instead of dealing with any kind of OS-specific, shell-involved tooling at all? It adds some IPC overhead, but also removes the `execve()` and module-initialization-time overhead you're creating by starting a whole new interpreter (vs `fork()`ing off copies of an existing one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can one of these work for you?

```
parallel --keep-order myexperiment ::: a r g s 1 ::: a r g s 2 > output-in-order
parallel --results mydir/ myexperiment ::: a r g s 1 ::: a r g s 2
parallel --results myfile{1}-{2} myexperiment ::: a r g s 1 ::: a r g s 2
parallel --results myfile.tsv myexperiment ::: a r g s 1 ::: a r g s 2
```

If you are a scientist, the last one is interesting because it can be read directly by R.

Answer (score 0):

You launch all the scripts at once (for example in a loop), and each script redirects its result to a separate file

To do this use in the naming of test logs for example:

```
Log_file_name. $$. Log => Log_file_name.1548.log
```

`$$`: return the process number of the script (which is a single value)

I hope this can help you